# How to add a keyword shortcut without conflicting or overriding other existing shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to add a shortcut `alt+left` to '**move selected text left**' but actually there are 3 more commands using that shortcut.

The thing is I don't know the options available to when condition. I thought maybe using '**editorTextFocus**' or '**textInputFocus**' would make the shortcut more precise but nah. Also not sure if they mean: **when the text is selected use this shortcut**. But just gave it a shot. **I'm looking for ny when condition that have that meaning??**

There should be a way to add same shortcuts with different purpose in different cases right? Finding the ones(shortcuts) that are not being used doesn't make any sense. Because to be remembered they must have a meaningful key combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use this command when there is a selection in the editor that has the focus

```txt
"when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you. Anyway, wouldn't just editorHasSelection do all the job itself? What's the use of editorTextFocus?

Comment: if you don't use `editorTextFocus` the keybinding will also work if other parts have focus and that means the other `Alt-Left` bindings are blocked